# Install über jar with maven-shaded-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

I have been using maven assembly plugin to create uber jar and deploy to Artifactory.
I switched to maven shade plugin to shade some dependencies.
Now my jar is not deployed during install phase.

In the maven assembly plugin documentation:

> When the assembly is created it will use the assemblyId as the
> artifact's classifier and will attach the created assembly to the
> project so that it will be uploaded into the repository in the install
> and deploy phase.

This is not a case for shaded plugin.
How to configure maven pom to deploy uber jar created with shaded plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell [maven-shade-plugin to attach](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/attached-artifact.html) the shaded artifact which can be done via:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
              <shadedClassifierName>jackofall</shadedClassifierName> <!-- Any name that makes sense -->
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: thank you very much :) this is exactly what I have been looking for :)

Comment: Use "uber" for the classifier name and the following for modules to use the uber jar as a dependency: 
     <dependency>
   <groupId>abc</groupId>
   <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
   <classifier>uber</classifier>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, where `mvn install` would build a shaded jar in my target directory but install the non-shaded one to my local Maven repository.

What ultimately proved to be the cause was that I had `<finalName>` defined in my maven-shade-plugin configuration. That ended up saving the shaded jar under that specific name, while the non-shaded jar took the default jar name which `mvn install` must look for when it comes time to install. Without `<finalName>` present, it copied the shaded jar appropriately into the local Maven repository.

With `<shadedArtifactAttached>`, I could get the shaded jar installed, but only suffixed with `shadedClassifierName` while the non-shaded jar was present under the normal artifact name, causing libraries dependent on it to pick up the non-shaded jar over the shaded one (which was not what I wanted in this case as I'm building a library with some dependencies shaded).